# POST request to a specific address is not created

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote the following POST request to the address "https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments/"

```
  await http
      .post(Uri.parse('https://api.yookassa.ru/v3/payments/'))
      .then((value) {
    print('BODY: ${value.body}');
  });
```

But when I try to run this code, the VS Code icon just starts flashing orange as if there was an error, when in fact there is not. The emulator just freezes and you have to restart it. By the way, I didn’t find any errors except this one:

[image]